# Caching the value of a method in react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming from an Ember background which had computed properties that were lazily computed and then cached until the dependent properties change.

Say I have the following setup in react:

```
export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Smith'
        }
    },

    fullName: function(){
        console.log('full name is computed')
        return `${this.state.firstName} ${this.state.lastName}`;
    },

    changeFirstName: function(){
        this.setState({ firstName: 'somethingElse'});
    },

    changeUnrelatedState: function(){
        this.setState({ blah: 'zzzzzz' });
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>{this.state.firstName} and {this.state.lastName} makes {this.fullName()}</div>

            <button onClick={this.changeFirstName}>Change first name</button
            <button onClick={this.changeUnrelatedState}>Change some state variable</button
        );
    }
});
```

When I click the 'Change some state variable' button, the component re-renders and the `fullName` method recomputes. This is a simple example, but what if the fullName method performed an expensive computation? This would run every single time the state changes, regardless of whether or not `firstName` or `lastName` changed but still triggering that expensive operation.

Is there a react way of caching the value of a method, and not re-computing it during each render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By extracting our expensive computation into a new component we can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` and only recalculate when needed. This way we get "caching" of already once computed values.

```
var FullNameComponent = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextProps, nextState) {
        //Props was the same no need for re-rendering
        if (nextProps.firstName === this.props.firstName) return false;

        //Props has changed, recalculate!
        return true;
    },
    performExpensiveCalculation: function () {
        console.log('rerenders');
        return `${this.props.firstName} ${this.props.lastName}`;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (<div>{this.performExpensiveCalculation()}</div>);
    }
});
```